# curl error code 404 while trying to install utop through opam in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is my docker file:

```
FROM ocaml/opam2
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN opam update
RUN opam install utop
RUN eval $(opam env)
CMD ["utop"]
RUN opam install ounit --dry-run
```

This is the error I get:

```
[ERROR] The sources of the following couldn't be obtained, aborting:
          - charInfo_width.1.1.0: curl error code 404
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c opam install utop]: exit code: 40
```

This docker file is the results of me trying to get utop to be installed. Ocaml gets installed just fine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.